# Swift: How to insert an UIImage at a particular index in a string?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to insert an UIImageView into a textView..It works but the position of my image is always at the corner of The textView.
Here is my code :

```
if(parseur.textStrings.containsString(SymboleList[i])){
   let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imagesSymboleList[i]))
   let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0,0, image.frame.width,       image.frame.height))
   parseur.textStrings.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(SymboleList[i], withString: "")             
   boiteTexte.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [path]
   boiteTexte.addSubview(image)
}
```

SymboleList is a list containing strings I want to replace with images (images are in imagesSymboleList)
I have to find the position of string I want to replace and insert my image at that index.
How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to insert image into the line like an emotikon or place it with `exclusionPath` yet to make neighbor lines float around it?

Comment: I want to put it into the line like an emotikon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve emoticon-like insertion of images

```
@IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

var SymboleList: [String] = ["ipsum", "incididunt", "Excepteur"];
var imagesSymboleList: [String] = ["img.png", "img.png", "img.png"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.insertImages();
}

func insertImages() {

    let attrString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.maximumLineHeight = (textView.font?.lineHeight)!
    attrString.addAttribute(
        NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: style, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

    for var i = 0; i < SymboleList.count; i++ {

        // get attachment image
        var image = UIImage(named: imagesSymboleList[i])
        let scaleFactor = (textView.font?.lineHeight)! / (image?.size.height)!
        let newSize = CGSizeMake((image?.size.width)! * scaleFactor, (image?.size.height)! * scaleFactor)
        image = self.scaleImage(image!, newSize: newSize)
        let attachment: NSTextAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
        attachment.image = image;

        // build attachment string
        let attachmentString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
        attachmentString.addAttribute(
            NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName,
            value: -(textView.font?.lineHeight)! / 4,
            range: NSMakeRange(0, attachmentString.length))

        // replace text with images
        let range = (attrString.string as NSString).rangeOfString(SymboleList[i])
        attrString.replaceCharactersInRange(range, withAttributedString: attachmentString)

    }

    textView.attributedText = attrString

}

func scaleImage(image: UIImage, newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0);
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

**Result**:
[image: Result]